# Coffeescript function running independent of event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I recently have built a notifications feature into my rails app from a tut I go from GoRails => [Here's the tut](https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-navbar-notifications)

The long and short of the approach was to create a notifications model which recorded associations between the users involved with some action (ie. making a post will create a notification b/t the poster and the owner of what was posted on).

Notifications also possess an attribute called 'read' which is false by default. From here is where the problem begins. While the notifications save properly, as soon as I log in as the user who's suppose to receive the notification, a POST request is sent to my server, changing 'read' to true. Below is the script & view that's suppose to be responsible for making the request.

```
class Notifications
constructor: ->
    @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
    @setup() if @notifications.length > 0 

setup: -> 
    $("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on "click", @handleClick ->

    $.ajax(
        url: "/notifications.json"
        dataType: "JSON"
        method: "GET"
        success: @handleSuccess
    )
handleClick: (e) =>
    $.ajax(
        url: "/notifications/mark_as_read"
        dataType: "JSON"
        method: "POST"
        success: ->
            $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text("")                
    )
handleSuccess: (data) =>
   console.log(data) 
   items = $.map data, (notification) ->
        "<a class='dropdown-item' href='#{notification.url}'>#{notification.actor} #{notification.action} #{notification.notifiable.type}</a>"
    console.log(items)

    $("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html(items)
    $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(items.length)
    if items.length is 0
        $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text("")               

jQuery ->
     new Notifications
```

And the view:

```
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" data-behavior='notifications' data-behavior="notifications-link">
      <a id="notificationsDD" href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <%= fa_icon("bell") %><span data-behavior='unread-count'></span>
      </a>

      <div class="dropdown-menu" data-behavior="notification-items" aria-labelledby="notificationsDD">
      <!--
      <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>yeo</a>
       -->
      </div>
    </li>
```

From tinkering with the script, it seems like the @handleClick function is running by itself w/o the click event occurring.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your CoffeeScript to match what it really looks like? Indentation defines the structure of CoffeeScript code so it is important to get it right.

Comment: I think it's formatted properly. For reference, it's just the code from the tut which I linked to, if you scroll down the page, toward the bottom but before the comments, you'll see what I'm talking about

Comment: Look at the JavaScript for [this version](https://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Notifications%0Aconstructor%3A%20-%3E) and [this (correct) version](https://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Notifications%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E) and you'll see what I mean about the indentation. I'm pretty sure the problem is only in the question's formatting though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that your CoffeeScript really looks like this:

```
class Notifications
    constructor: ->
        @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
        @setup() if @notifications.length > 0 

    setup: -> 
        $("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on "click", @handleClick ->

    #...
```

as that matches the behavior you're seeing.

In that case, the problem would be in your `setup` method:

```
$("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on "click", @handleClick ->
```

Adding method-calling parentheses shows us the problem:

```
$("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on("click", @handleClick(->))
```

You're calling `@handleClick` with an (empty) anonymous function as its argument while building the argument list to `on`. You probably want to bind `handleClick` to the `'click'` event so you want to say:

```
$("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on "click", @handleClick
```

to pass the `@handleClick` function as an argument without calling it.

Comment: You're the man, brother. But could you clear one thing up for me? I though '->' is CS equivalent to JS () which is just the function invocation operator. Why would that function just run itself even though it's binded to the click even?

Comment: (x) -> ...` in CoffeeScript is like `function(x) { ... }` in JavaScript. Functions are called the same way in CoffeeScript as in JavaScript except that the parentheses are sometimes optional. `@handleClick` is like `this.handleClick` so it is just a reference to the function.